# Installing randomlib with composer

Tags: php, random, composer-php

I am attempting to install the randomlib in order to generate secure random strings for my project, but the documentation does not include a guideline for installation (especially in a way that would be understandable to somebody new to github)

I am trying to run

```
php composer.php ircmaxell/RandomLib
```

but get an execption saying that composer cannot find a stable package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `composer.json` include:

```
{
    "require": {
        ...
        "ircmaxell/random-lib" : "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Then run `composer update`

Comment: It's really a bad idea to use "dev-master" as a version.

Answer (score 2):

The commandline command you should be using: `php composer.php require ircmaxell/random-lib`.

You were not using the `require` part and the wrong package name. If you are unsure which name is correct, go to https://packagist.org and do a quick search, like this: https://packagist.org/search/?q=ircmaxell%2Frandom

Result: https://packagist.org/packages/ircmaxell/random-lib

That page, right at the top, gives you the full command line to add it.

Additionally, avoid using branch versions, always opt for tagged releases. Branches will give you trouble in the long run, i.e. it will work at first, and depending on what the developer of that other package will push to the branch, it will fail at some point after you updates. Recovering from such dependencies is usually hard work, so it is best to avoid it from the start.